# How to read a column from a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I currently am using pandas to read from a csv file but I'm trying to remove the index column, Name and dtype from my output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Book2.csv')
list = [df['Column1']]
print (list)
```

Output:

```
[0     ST
1    VC
2     ST
3     ST
4    ST
5     CO
6     UT
Name: Column1, dtype: object]
```

Comment: Just slice it? Df1 = df1['column1']

Comment: df['Column1'].tolist()?

Comment: Every `DataFrame` and `Series` must have an index, you can't get around that. If you truly think you don't need it, then ignore it, manipulate your data and when you save it just use `df.to_csv('file_name', index=False)` and it will be gone. Or  use a different library like `numpy`, you can access the underlying array with `df.values`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want the values, you can add `list = df.values` to the list. If you are trying to append to a list, you can do `list += df.values` after initializing `list`.